# AngularFire2 query, join or filter with foreign keys from another firebase table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I have this firebase data structure

```
{
  members: {
    m1: {
     lastName: "smith",
     firstName: "john"
    },
    m2: {
     lastName: "abc",
     firstName: "mike"
    }
  },
  userFavs: {
    u1: {
       m1:true
    },
    u2: {
       m2:true
    }
  }
}
```

In my service, I have this method:

```
  getMembers(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('/members',{
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'firstName'
      }
    });
  }
```

In members page TS file, I have method to do search:

```
  setFilteredItems(){
    if (this.searchTerm == null || this.searchTerm == ''){
      this.members = this.membersSvc.getMembers()
        .map((members) => {return members});
    }else{
      //return items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
      this.members = this.membersSvc.getMembers()
        .map((members) =>
          members.filter(member => member.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || member.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1));
    }
  }
```

The search for members is working fine. Now I am adding 2 buttons below the search bar, **All** and **Favorites**. A user can add a member in his/her favorites. In search, the app needs to be able to filter the results with member keys that exists in the user favorites.

How can I add the additional filter of member keys that exists in the userFavs node?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've asked a question or presented an error here.

Comment: @Kato thanks! i updated it with question.

Answer (score 0):

I added the additional filter by getting the array of userFavs keys. So in my user service I have a method:

```
  getUserFavKeys(){
    let favKeys = [];
    const userKey = this.authService.getActiveUser().uid;
    let url = `/userCircles/${userKey}`;
    this.af.database.list(url, { preserveSnapshot: true})
      .subscribe(itemKeys=>{
        itemKeys.forEach(itemKey => {
          //console.log(itemKey.key);
          favKeys.push(itemKey.key);
        });
      })
    return favKeys;
  }
```

Then in the component `ngOnInit` method, I initialized the array of keys:

```
this.favKeys = this.userSvc.getUserFavKeys();
```

And when the circles is selected:

```
onCirclesSelected(){
    this.searching = false;
    this.members = this.membersSvc.getMembers()
        .map((members) =>
            members.filter(member => this.userCircles.indexOf(member.$key) !== -1)
        );

    if (this.searchTerm == null || this.searchTerm == ''){
            //do nothing
    }else{
        //filter w the search text
        this.members = this.members
            .map((members) =>
                members.filter(member => member.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || member.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps to anyone that needs the same search feature.

Comment: let url = `/userCircles/${userKey}`;
Does this have to be bound to a function

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Thnx

Comment: That userKey is a dynamic value right? is that how you change between PATHS, I am trying to work out he best way to have a dyanmic path.

Comment: Yes. Looking at that code again, I could have written as `let url = \`/userCircles/${this.authService.getActiveUser().uid}\`;` to avoid the `const userKey` declaration.

Comment: I tried that with the offline librabry and it keeps failing. It wont accept it, by any chance have you used that wrapper?

Comment: Can you try taking out the `preserveSnapshot` if it works?

Comment: with the offline angularfire2 there is no snapshop